# How to make local port mappings with iptables

Tags: iptables

I usually have this command to do the local port mapping

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:127.0.0.1:8080
```

So whenever the client talks to port 80 of my machine, it talks to port 8080 actually.

It is actually a proxy.

I am wondering if I could use iptables, instead of running a proxy, to achieve the same goal. Like, I tried the following command, which doesn't work.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <my-ip> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080
```

#### UPDATE

The command above should've worked, but it didn't, because there were other `iptables` rules affecting it.

So without other rules, the following 3 commands all work.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <my-ip> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <my-ip>:8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <my-ip> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <my-ip>:8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <my-ip> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <my-ip>:8080
```

Thank you @AlexD. After read your answer, I started over the test much more carefully, and figured out this. Also thanks @Ginnungagap, the `REDIRECT` target you showed me is more simple and straightforward.

###### New question

I now have a new question based on the test result, which looks like a `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` target is not necessary in my case, why? I thought a `SNAT` is mandatory for a `DNAT` rule.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d <your-ip> --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <your-ip>:8080
```

Comment: `-j REDIRECT --to-port 80` will save you having to duplicate your local IP.

Comment: @Ginnungagap I was not aware of the `REDIRECT` target. I learned. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexD. Thank you for your answer. It works. However, actually, the original `iptables` command line posted in my question also works. It didn't work because there were other `iptables` rules affecting this one. I am gonna update my question to reflect the findings.